# Calculating combination IDs in MySQL and then storing them for stock

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Okay, I'm pulling my hair out with this.

I have a table called products_bind_variant

```
itemId int(10)
productId int(10)
variantId int(10)
```

The variantId references a type, be it size, colour etc.

This table is variant

```
variantId int(10)
name varchar(150)
grouping varchar(150)
```

The grouping value would be something like Size, Colour, Range etc etc

My variant tavble data is here:

```
|1|Small|Size
|2|Medium|Size
|3|Large|Size
|4|Red|Colour
|5|White|Colour
|6|Blue|Colour
|7|Extra Large|Size
|8|1-3 years|Range
|9|3-10|Range
```

My products_bind_variant data is here:

```
|1|69|5
|7|69|6
|8|69|8
|9|69|9
|10|69|4
|12|69|1
|18|69|3
|19|69|2
|20|69|7
```

I want to query to work out the combinations of variantId on itself and only show Ids of combinations of the same group.

I tried using

```
SELECT a.productsid,
       a.variantid,
       b.variantid
FROM   products_bind_variant a
       INNER JOIN products_bind_variant b
               ON a.variantid < b.variantid
```

However, that returns 36 results because it's matching up itself against itself. I need it to take into account to only finding combinations between the grouping type which would be 24 combinations.

So basically something like querying the Ids.

So

`69| 1,4,8` for Small,Red,1-3 years

Here are the combinations I need to generate, but not the names, the variantId

```
Blue, 1-3 Years, Extra Large
Blue, 3-10 Years, Extra Large
Blue, 1-3 Years, Large
Blue, 3-10 Years, Large
Blue, 1-3 Years, Medium
Blue, 3-10 Years, Medium
Blue, 1-3 Years, Small
Blue, 3-10 Years, Small
Red, 1-3 Years, Extra Large
Red, 3-10 Years, Extra Large
Red, 1-3 Years, Large
Red, 3-10 Years, Large
Red, 1-3 Years, Medium
Red, 3-10 Years, Medium
Red, 1-3 Years, Small
Red, 3-10 Years, Small
White, 1-3 Years, Extra Large
White, 3-10 Years, Extra Large
White, 1-3 Years, Large
White, 3-10 Years, Large
White, 1-3 Years, Medium
White, 3-10 Years, Medium
White, 1-3 Years, Small
White, 3-10 Years, Small
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Thanks, provided some data now

Comment: The data you added is from the variant table but you want to query the products_bind_variant table, right? Add sample data and expected output that is relevant for your query.

Comment: Yes, want to query the products_bind_variant table but to take into account the grouping from variant so it doesn't show results of small and large combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce 24 rows:

```
select
      `colour`, `range`, `size`, cid, sid, rid
from (select variantId cid, name `colour` from  variant where grouping = 'Colour') c
cross join (select variantId sid, name `size` from  variant where grouping = 'Size') s
cross join (select variantId rid, name `range` from  variant where grouping = 'Range') r

+----+--------+-----------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+
|    | colour |   range   |    size     | cid | sid | rid |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 | Red    | 1-3 years | Small       |   4 |   1 |   8 |
|  2 | White  | 1-3 years | Small       |   5 |   1 |   8 |
|  3 | Blue   | 1-3 years | Small       |   6 |   1 |   8 |
|  4 | Red    | 1-3 years | Medium      |   4 |   2 |   8 |
|  5 | White  | 1-3 years | Medium      |   5 |   2 |   8 |
|  6 | Blue   | 1-3 years | Medium      |   6 |   2 |   8 |
|  7 | Red    | 1-3 years | Large       |   4 |   3 |   8 |
|  8 | White  | 1-3 years | Large       |   5 |   3 |   8 |
|  9 | Blue   | 1-3 years | Large       |   6 |   3 |   8 |
| 10 | Red    | 1-3 years | Extra Large |   4 |   7 |   8 |
| 11 | White  | 1-3 years | Extra Large |   5 |   7 |   8 |
| 12 | Blue   | 1-3 years | Extra Large |   6 |   7 |   8 |
| 13 | Red    | 3-10      | Small       |   4 |   1 |   9 |
| 14 | White  | 3-10      | Small       |   5 |   1 |   9 |
| 15 | Blue   | 3-10      | Small       |   6 |   1 |   9 |
| 16 | Red    | 3-10      | Medium      |   4 |   2 |   9 |
| 17 | White  | 3-10      | Medium      |   5 |   2 |   9 |
| 18 | Blue   | 3-10      | Medium      |   6 |   2 |   9 |
| 19 | Red    | 3-10      | Large       |   4 |   3 |   9 |
| 20 | White  | 3-10      | Large       |   5 |   3 |   9 |
| 21 | Blue   | 3-10      | Large       |   6 |   3 |   9 |
| 22 | Red    | 3-10      | Extra Large |   4 |   7 |   9 |
| 23 | White  | 3-10      | Extra Large |   5 |   7 |   9 |
| 24 | Blue   | 3-10      | Extra Large |   6 |   7 |   9 |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

There are 9 rows in the variant table for the only productid: 3 colours, 2 ranges, and 4 sizes

```
SELECT
    b.productid, v.grouping, group_concat(v.name order by v.name separator ',') as variants
FROM products_bind_variant b
inner join variant v on b.variantid = v.variantid
group  by b.productid, v.grouping

+----+-----------+----------+--------------------------------+
|    | productid | grouping |            variants            |
+----+-----------+----------+--------------------------------+
|  1 |        69 | Colour   | Blue,Red,White                 |
|  2 |        69 | Range    | 1-3 years,3-10                 |
|  3 |        69 | Size     | Extra Large,Large,Medium,Small |
+----+-----------+----------+--------------------------------+
```

data used:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products_bind_variant;
CREATE TABLE products_bind_variant(
   itemId    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,productId INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,variantId INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO products_bind_variant(itemId,productId,variantId) VALUES (1,69,5);
INSERT INTO products_bind_variant(itemId,productId,variantId) VALUES (7,69,6);
INSERT INTO products_bind_variant(itemId,productId,variantId) VALUES (8,69,8);
INSERT INTO products_bind_variant(itemId,productId,variantId) VALUES (9,69,9);
INSERT INTO products_bind_variant(itemId,productId,variantId) VALUES (10,69,4);
INSERT INTO products_bind_variant(itemId,productId,variantId) VALUES (12,69,1);
INSERT INTO products_bind_variant(itemId,productId,variantId) VALUES (18,69,3);
INSERT INTO products_bind_variant(itemId,productId,variantId) VALUES (19,69,2);
INSERT INTO products_bind_variant(itemId,productId,variantId) VALUES (20,69,7);

DROP TABLE if exists variant;
CREATE TABLE variant(
   variantId INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,name      VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
  ,grouping  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO variant(variantId,name,grouping) VALUES (1,'Small','Size');
INSERT INTO variant(variantId,name,grouping) VALUES (2,'Medium','Size');
INSERT INTO variant(variantId,name,grouping) VALUES (3,'Large','Size');
INSERT INTO variant(variantId,name,grouping) VALUES (4,'Red','Colour');
INSERT INTO variant(variantId,name,grouping) VALUES (5,'White','Colour');
INSERT INTO variant(variantId,name,grouping) VALUES (6,'Blue','Colour');
INSERT INTO variant(variantId,name,grouping) VALUES (7,'Extra Large','Size');
INSERT INTO variant(variantId,name,grouping) VALUES (8,'1-3 years','Range');
INSERT INTO variant(variantId,name,grouping) VALUES (9,'3-10','Range');
```

Comment: I updated the original answer with the data I need to produce with the 24 combinations.  I need that but listing the ids.

Comment: and I have suggested a revised query in response

Comment: Just one more question, is there any way to automatically generate the combinations as a CONCAT string without knowing the value in the grouping and not having to specify the " where grouping = 'Colour' part .  It's not a bigger as I can get PHP to generate this when work out the makeup.

Comment: I would use PHP for that. It isn't simple at all in SQL

Comment: Great stuff, I've already started doing that.  You've helped me so much, my proposed model for the stock now works due to the query solution provided :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all the variants for each grouping for a product.  If so, think aggregation rather than `JOIN`:

```
SELECT v.grouping,
       pbv.productsid,
       grouup_concat(pbv.variantid) as variants
FROM products_bind_variant pbv JOIN
     variant v
     ON pvb1.variantid = v1.variantid 
GROUP BY v.grouping;
```

Comment: Thank you, but that returns 9 results, there should be 24 combinations.  I need to work out the combinations of all.  My original query, gave 36  because small for example was checking against a combination of medium. I need to omit the combination checking it's own type.